# You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream

Tags: javascript, django, django-views, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I keep getting the following error when trying to post to PayPal:

```
shippingData = json.loads(request.body)

django.http.request.RawPostDataException: You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream
```

I have tried removing the request.headers, this does nothing. I tried removing CRSF Token altogether and still the same error. I have also tried renaming request.body into a different variable, this also does not remove the error.  Replacing with request.data just gives a different error also.

This is my view:

```
def create_order(request):
    customer = Customer.objects.get(user=request.user)
    shippingData = json.loads(request.body)
    first_name = customer.first_name
    last_name = customer.last_name
    
    ShippingAddress.objects.create(
        customer=customer,
        house=shippingData['shipping']['house'],
        street=shippingData['shipping']['street'],
        city=shippingData['shipping']['city'],
        postcode=shippingData['shipping']['postcode'],
    )

    # assuming you have retrieved the ShippingAddress object for the given customer
    shipping_address_queryset = ShippingAddress.objects.filter(customer=customer)
    if shipping_address_queryset.exists():
        shipping_address = shipping_address_queryset.first()

    # extract the necessary fields from the shipping_address object
    house = shipping_address.house
    street = shipping_address.street
    city = shipping_address.city
    postcode = shipping_address.postcode
    
    user_cart = Cart.objects.filter(user=request.user).first()

    if user_cart:
    # get cart items and total
        cart_items = user_cart.items.all()
        cart_total = user_cart.get_cart_total()

        # create the items list
        items = []
        for item in cart_items:
            items.append({
                "name": item.product.title,
                "description": "",
                "quantity": str(item.quantity),
                "unit_amount": {
                    "currency_code": "GBP",
                    "value": "{:.2f}".format(item.product.price)
                },
                "tax": {
                    "currency_code": "GBP",
                    "value": "0.00"
                }
            })

        # calculate the breakdown for the purchase unit
        item_total = sum(float(item["unit_amount"]["value"]) * int(item["quantity"]) for item in items)
        amount_breakdown = {
            "item_total": {
                "currency_code": "GBP",
                "value": "{:.2f}".format(item_total)
            },
            "shipping": {
                "currency_code": "GBP",
                "value": "0.00"
            },
        }
    
    access_token = settings.PAYPAL_ACCESS_TOKEN
    # Create a new PayPal order
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-CSRFToken': request.headers['X-CSRFToken'],
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token,
    }
    data = {
        "intent": "CAPTURE",
        "paypal": {
                "experience_context": {
                    "payment_method_preference": "IMMEDIATE_PAYMENT_REQUIRED",
                    "payment_method_selected": "PAYPAL",
                    "brand_name": "Martin Henson Prints",
                    "locale": "en-GB",
                    "landing_page": "LOGIN",
                    "user_action": "PAY_NOW",
                    "shipping_preference": "SET_PROVIDED_ADDRESS",
                }
            },
        "purchase_units": [{
            "amount": {
                "currency_code": "GBP",
                "value": "{:.2f}".format(cart_total),
                "breakdown": amount_breakdown
            },
            "items": items,
            "shipping": {
                    "name": {
                        "full_name": f"{first_name} {last_name}"
                    },
                    "address": {
                        "address_line_1": f"{house} {street}",
                        "admin_area_2": city,
                        "postal_code": postcode,
                        "country_code": "GB"
                    }
                }
            }]
        }

    response = requests.post('https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders', headers=headers, json=data)
```

**EDIT: ADDED SCRIPT FOR MORE CONTEXT**

```
 paypal.Buttons({
        createOrder: function(data, actions, form) {
              var form = document.getElementById('form');
              var shippingInfo = {
                  house: form.house.value,
                  street: form.street.value,
                  city: form.city.value, 
                  postcode: form.postcode.value
              };

              return fetch('/create_order/', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                  'content-type': 'application/json',
                  'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                  shipping: shippingInfo,
                })
              }).then(function(response) {
                return response.json();
              }).then(function(orderData) {
                return orderData.orderID;
              }).then(function(orderID) {
                // Call the orderCreate function here
                orderCreate();
                return orderID;
              });
            },
            onApprove: function(data, actions) {
              return fetch('/capture_payment/', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                  'content-type': 'application/json',
                  'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                  orderID: data.orderID
                })
              }).then(function(response) {
                return response.json();
              }).then(function(captureData) {
                updateOrder();
              });
            }
          }).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

Comment: Use request.data , which should already be parsed JSON. What is the different error?

Comment: Hi @PrestonPHX, when I edit the line to shippingData = json.loads(request.data) I get the following error:   
AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'data'. I have added my script incase anything is wrong on there.

Comment: I found my issue, it was because I was calling the view in my action="" on form also.